# how do I make the scanned barcode data from the camera to go to the user entry field? this is two different codes i tried to merge

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, python-imaging-library, barcode

I need this to take the decoded data from the webcam and use the data as user entry. I tried merging two codes and not getting very far with it at the moment. any assistanc on this is greatly appreciated.

one code currently takes user input and displays image and another code allows me to scan the barcode using my webcam.

**CODE 1: this will take user input and displays picture using the input.**

```
from os import link
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


root = Tk()
root.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
root.title("Images")
root.geometry("600x800")


def myClick(self):
    try:
        link = r'scanpicsorig\\'+ e.get()[slice(42,52)]+'.jpg'
        my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(link))
        my_label.configure(image=my_img)
        my_label.image = my_img
        e.delete(0, END)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        link = r'scanpicsorig\\Backup.jpg'
        my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(link))
        my_label.configure(image=my_img)
        my_label.image = my_img
        e.delete(0, END)


e = Entry(root, width=50, bg='light blue', borderwidth=3)
e.pack()
e.insert(0, '')
e.focus_set()
e.bind('<Return>', myClick)


button_quit = Button(root, text='Exit Program', command=root.quit)
button_quit.pack()

my_label = Label()
my_label.pack(padx=15, pady=20)
frame = LabelFrame(root, padx=800, pady=800)
frame.pack(padx=800, pady=800)


root.mainloop()
```

**CODE 2: this opens the camera and is able to scan and decode barcode.**

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera

while True:
    _, frame = cap.read()

    decodedObjects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
    for obj in decodedObjects:
        print("data", obj.data)
        
    
    cv2.imshow("frame", frame)

    key = cv2.waitKey(1)
    if key == 27:
        break
```

Comment: please fix your post's formatting. there's no way for me to fix this for you because you destroyed the indentation as well. -- your code looks like you just glued two different scripts together. that won't work. please review [ask].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz i have edited the codes and separated the two into different ones.When i run the first one, it does what i need it to do. second one does it too. how do i get the decoded data and use it as user input? thanks for the  how to ask guide. it should be the correct format now. your help is appreciated.

Comment: Pedantic comment:  Why use `[slice(42,52)]` instead of simply `[42:52]`?

Comment: Are you running these as two separate programs or do you want to put them into a single program? If the same program you want to learn about threading and queues, possibly.  If different, you could look in to socket communications or write the code to a file with one code and read it with the other (watching for file system changes).

Comment: you may need to run cv2 code in separated thread. Or you have to use `.after(time, function)` instead loop `while True` - and run code every few milliseconds, and this will not block GUI. And you will have to run `cv2` without `imshow` and `waitkey`

Comment: @RufusVS i am trying to combine these two into one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `threading` to run `cv2` code in separated thread but it better to get code from loop and create function which check image only once, and use `root.after(100, function)` to run it every 100ms without blocking GUI.

And you don't need `imshow()`,`waitKey()` to display it. You can convert `frame` to `PIL.Image` and display in `tkinter.

```
#from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk  # PEP8: `import * is not preferred
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

import cv2
import pyzbar.pyzbar as pyzbar

# --- functions ---

def my_click(self):
    try:
        link = r'scanpicsorig\\'+ e.get()[slice(42,52)]+'.jpg'
        my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(link))
        my_label.configure(image=my_img)
        my_label.image = my_img
        e.delete(0, END)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        link = r'scanpicsorig\\Backup.jpg'
        my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open(link))
        my_label.configure(image=my_img)
        my_label.image = my_img
        e.delete(0, END)

def check_barcode():
    
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    
    if ret:
        decoded_objects = pyzbar.decode(frame)
        
        for obj in decoded_objects:
            print("data", obj.data)
            e.insert(0, obj.data)

        RGB_frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        my_img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.fromarray(RGB_frame))
        my_label.configure(image=my_img)
        my_label.image = my_img
            
        #cv2.imshow('preview', frame)
        #cv2.waitKey(1)  # update image in `imshow`
        
    root.after(100, check_barcode)  # run again after 100ms 

# --- mai ---

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
#cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0, cv2.CAP_DSHOW) #captureDevice = camera

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("600x800")

e = tk.Entry(root, width=50, bg='light blue', borderwidth=3)
e.pack()

e.focus_set()
e.bind('<Return>', my_click)

button_quit = tk.Button(root, text='Exit Program', command=root.quit)
button_quit.pack()

frame = tk.LabelFrame(root)
frame.pack()

my_label = tk.Label(frame)
my_label.pack()

check_barcode()  # run first time

root.mainloop()

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()  # can be needed if you use `cv2.imshow`
```

[image]

---

But with this code can be other problem. It runs loop all time. If it detect barcode then it could copy data to Entry, but in next loop it would do the same with different value - so it may need some variable `True`/`False` to inform that code was already detected and there is no need to detect again.

Comment: thank you @furus I tried the method. the user entry is now filled with how the camera decodes but the GUI does not display the image of what is decoded any longer. i will play around with this and see if i can get it to work.

Comment: opencv displays its image when waitkey is called.

Comment: @RufusVS I even mentioned something like this as comment in code :) But OP didn't explain if problem is with `OpenCV window` or with `Tkinter window`. OP also uses button to display some image and maybe this makes problem. We may need to wait for details.

Comment: Hello @furas and i have tried it and it works. the issue I have is with the Tkinter window where after the decoded info is in the text box it does not hit enter all by it self. also, the picture that is displayed goes away in miliseconds. i want it to hit enter and the picture to stay displayed until the barcode (same or different) is scanned again. I am very excited for this project and how far i have come with it. thanks to you furus i am able to do this.